# "Microsoft Resource File to COFF Object Conversion Utility has stopped working" error when compiling

Tags: c#, resources, coff

For reasons that are unknown to me, I have recently been getting an error when compiling my C# applications that simply states

"`Microsoft Resource File to COFF Object Conversion Utility has stopped working`".

In the error list, there always appears an error that says

"`'[project folder]\obj\x86\Debug\CSC[random number].tmp' is not a valid Win32 resource file`".

I've been google-ing this problem for the past hour now, and the only actually solution anyone's come up with is running `sfc /scannow` in the elevated command prompt. Well, it found nothing corrupted for me, and there doesn't really seem to be any questions here about it. I'm hoping somebody could give me a solution to this problem.

Comment: This sounds like a corrupt file. What kind of project is this? Try doing a Clean from Solutions Explorer before doing another build.

Answer (score 5):

I am using VS C++ but have had a very similar error, not sure what you are using.
I too trawled the web looking for fixes and what finally did it (which I should have done much earlier) was the **update to VS C++ SP1**.
Hopefully this is applicable to you and helps.